# Ember Simple Auth How to Redirect to login After Session Invalidate?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using ember simple auth and when I log out and the session invalidates I am redirected back to the root of the site. How do I redirect it to the login route on invalidate session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use authenticated route mixin in your route, which should be accessible after authentication:

```
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  // route you would like to redirect to after logout
  authenticationRoute: "routes.login",

  // ... your stuff ...
})
```

In root application route use also corresponding mixin:

```
import ApplicationRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/application-route-mixin';

ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend(ApplicationRouteMixin, {
  // route you would like to redirect to after login
  routeAfterAuthentication: "routes.authenticated-route",

  // ... your stuff
})
```

It depends on your needs, how you will use it. You can put it in every authenticated route, or for example you can put it in one route (eg. called "/auth") and put another authenticated routes into this route. Each of these routes will be also authenticated, your routing structure could look like this:

```
/
  login
  auth
    alsoAuthenticatedRoute
      someAuthenticatedDetailRoute
    anotherAuthenticatedRoute
      anotherAuthenticatedDetailRoute
```

Comment: Thanks! Where would the top block of code go exactly? Every route? I have a site wide authentication where every route will require authentication. Can I run this at the application level or will I need to check at each route?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for read session

```
this.get('session.data.currentUser')
```

handle that whatever you want.

app/router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('posts');
  this.route('post', { path: '/post/:post_id' });
```

});

app/routes/index.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  afterModel(model, transition) {
    if (model.get('length') === 1) {
       this.transitionTo('post', model.get('firstObject'));
    }
 } 
});
```

Use this